# Adding a custom field to Plone groups

Tags: plone

Using Plone 4.2, how can I add a field/property to Plone groups? Beside default ones (name, title, description, email) I'd like to have one more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try your luck with

```
http://localhost:8080/Plone/portal_groupdata/manage_propertiesForm
```

and report the results :) At least Site Setup's group edit form seems to be generic enough to support arbitrary number of fields (of all types).

Comment: Yup, works like a charm. Added a field through ZMI and it shows up on  @@usergroup-groupdetails. Awesome.

Comment: BTW, to do this in a GS upgrade: portal_groupdata.manage_addProperty('foo', '', 'string')

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the respective place for user data fields is `portal_memberdata/manage_propertiesForm`.