# Plone: Add additional registration fields to users (members)

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have two additional fields for my group objects (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10193359/1051649)).
Now I need (other) additional fields for my member objects as well (short strings).  I have created them in `portal_memberdata/manage_propertiesForm`, but I still can't select them for registration form usage (`@@member-registration`).

I need the two new fields for registration, at least one of them mandatory. How can I achieve this?  Thank you!

**Update:**
I found `plone.app.users.userdataschema` and added my fields to the interface `IUserDataSchema`; furthermore, I monkeypatched `plone.app.users.browser.personalpreferences.UserDataPanelAdapter`. There still seems to be missing something (no change visible in `@@member-registration`).

My customization code looks like this:

```
from plone.app.users.userdataschema import IUserDataSchema
from zope import schema
from Products.CMFPlone import PloneMessageFactory as _

IUserDataSchema.custom1 = schema.ASCIILine(
        title=_(u'label_custom1',
                default=u'Custom1 member id'),
        description=_(u'help_custom1_creation',
                      default=u'Custom1 membership is required; '
                      u'please enter your member id'),
        required=True)

from plone.app.users.browser.personalpreferences import UserDataPanelAdapter

def set_custom1(self, value):
    if value is None:
        value = ''
    return self.context.setMemberProperties({'custom1': value})

def get_custom1(self):
    return self._getProperty('custom1')

UserDataPanelAdapter.custom1 = property(get_custom1, set_custom1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't work when I used the monkeypatched original interface class;
but it *does* work to monkeypatch the `UserDataSchemaProvider` to return a subclass:

```py
from plone.app.users.userdataschema import IUserDataSchema
from plone.app.users.userdataschema import UserDataSchemaProvider
from zope import schema
from Products.CMFPlone import PloneMessageFactory as _


class IUserDataSchemaExtended(IUserDataSchema):
    """
    Extends the userdata schema
    by a mandatory field
    """
    customField1 = schema.ASCIILine(
        title=_(u'label_customField1',
                default=u'CustomField1 member id'),
        description=_(u'help_customField1_creation',
                      default=u'CustomField1 membership is required; '
                      u'please enter your member id'),
        required=True)

def getExtendedSchema(self):
    return IUserDataSchemaExtended

UserDataSchemaProvider.getSchema = getExtendedSchema

from plone.app.users.browser.personalpreferences import UserDataPanelAdapter

def set_customField1(self, value):
    if value is None:
        value = ''
    return self.context.setMemberProperties({'customField1': value})

def get_customField1(self):
    return self._getProperty('customField1')

UserDataPanelAdapter.customField1 = property(get_customField1, set_customField1)
```

**Remarks:**

- It might be better to simply use `customField1` for the translatable title instead of `label_customField` as the name the field is used when the registration page is `quickedit`ed
- with Plone 5, it apparently is possible to configure additional userdata fields via XML